# From security point of view what is the recommended value for access control allow origin header

Tags: ajax, http, cors

I do not want any cross domain calls to my domain. In such scenario,

1) Is **Same-Origin** a valid value for the header **Access Ccontrol Allow Origin** ?

2) If yes, is this value from  security point of view ?

3) If no, should I hardcode it to **mydomain.com**

Comment: If you don’t want to allow cross-origin requests to your domain, then don’t send back the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header at all. The same-origin policy already blocks frontend JavaScript code from access to responses from cross-origin requests. The purpose of the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header is for servers to tell browsers they want to opt into telling browsers to not enforce the protection of the same-origin policy for certain cases — that there are cases when they want to instead allow frontend JavaScript code to access responses for cross-origin requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want **any** cross-domain requests, just don't send any CORS response headers in the response - it's that easy.

Specific answers, if you **do** want to allow some domains (e.g. ones that you control) to allow cross-domain requests:

1) Is Same-Origin a valid value for the header Access-Control-Allow-Origin?

No, the only valid values for the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` (aka 'ACAO') header are `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` (allow any requesting domain) or `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: scheme://domain[:port]` which *exactly* matches the value of the Origin request header. Basically, you either return an asterisk, or just 'mirror back' the value of the Origin request header.

2) If yes, is this value from security point of view ?

If the question is "Is a value of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` secure?", the answer is that it depends entirely on your setup. Do you need to pass auth info (cookies, Authentication header etc.)? What are you trying to do? "Security" isn't really the right word here. Passing a value of `*` means that a request from any domain can retrieve your asset or make a call to your API. Is that a problem?

3) If no, should I hardcode it to mydomain.com

If you do so, you *must* include the scheme (and port, if it's not either 80 (for HTTP) or 443 (for HTTPS)).

If in doubt, do this (pseudo-code):

```
if (Origin header matches "*.mydomain.com" or Origin header matches "*://mydomain.com") {
    addheader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:" + [Origin header])
{
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your application architecture .
Suppose you are developing a system where your web application resides on different server with different domain and your service application (REST API's) resides on different server with different domain.

Then **only allowing same origin only will not work**. You will need to make cross domain calls from the web application.

So taking such decisions will vary according to your project architecture.
If you are sure about domain which will access that resource or REST API then you can restrict to the specific domain you want.